# Unable to run "ionic serve"

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, node-modules, sass-loader, postcss-loader

I downloaded my Ionic Cordova project from Github. I installed all the dependencies for the project. Whenever I run command, "ionic serve" I am getting this error.

```
ERROR in ./src/theme/variables.scss (./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/plugins/raw-css-loader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??embedded!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--14-3!./src/theme/variables.scss)
[ng] Module build failed (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js):
[ng] BrowserslistError: Unknown browser query `basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's`. Maybe you are using old Browserslist or made typo in query.
```

I did some research on the Internet to find solutions for this. I have tried solutions like adding

```
"stylePreprocessorOptions": {
  "includePaths": ["src/scss"]
}
```

I have not been able to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

install `node-sass` again

```
npm install node-sass
```